# I am having an error 'pyimage1' doesn't exist while opening image in turtle with tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter, python-turtle

Althogh it works perfectly fine with built in turtle shapes it doesn't work with
new registered shapes.The error is pyimage1 doesn't exist and both my program and file are in the same directories
Here is the code

````
      root=Tk()
      import turtle
      def image():
        global img
        img='batman.gif'
        player=turtle.Turtle()
        wn=turtle.Screen()
        wn.register_shape(img)
        player.shape(img)
      B=Button(root,text='click',command=image).pack()```

The error shown is:```Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
   return self.func(*args)
 File "C:\Users\dell\OneDrive\Desktop\imagetk.py", line 10, in image
   player.shape(img)
 File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 2777, in shape
   self.turtle._setshape(name)
 File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 2506, in _setshape
   self._item = screen._createimage(screen._shapes["blank"]._data)
 File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 723, in _createimage
   return self.cv.create_image(0, 0, image=image)
 File "<string>", line 1, in create_image
 File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2489, in create_image
   return self._create('image', args, kw)
 File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2480, in _create
   *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist```
````

Comment: try giving the full path of image

Comment: Thanks but I already tried that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the way you're mixing turtle and tkinter is creating two roots which leads to this error.  You're trying to use *standalone* turtle when you should be using *embedded* turtle.  I.e. you should be using `RawTurtle` instead of `Turtle` and `RawScreen` instead of `Screen`.  But don't just swap the names, look them up in the documentation.  Your code should look roughly like:

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import TurtleScreen, RawTurtle

IMAGE = 'batman.gif'

def image():
    player = RawTurtle(screen)
    player.shape(IMAGE)

root = Tk()

Button(root, text='click', command=image).pack()

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.register_shape(IMAGE)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank You so much I had been stuck on this for a while.The code is working perfectly now